# How to manage an Office365 group without permissions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have multiple Office365 private groups that I created using Outlook. I would like to be able to list, add and remove users using a Python script (or any other language). I am familiar with Microsoft graph API, and I have used it before.

I tried to use the graph API to manage the groups, but the permissions required to manage the group (`Group.ReadWrite.All`, `GroupMember.ReadWrite.All`) need an administrator's consent to be used. I cannot get admin consent within my organization, so is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think that Graph API provides some kind of hack to manage the group if you don't have required permissions.

Comment: I only want  to manage groups that I **own**

Comment: It doesn't matter that you are owner of the group. It doesn't give you the permissions for Graph API to manage groups you own. Currently is not supported. But maybe others know some workaround. We will see :)